# Create a Custom Spinner Adapter in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to make a `Spinner` with a custom adapter to display images with text like the following

[image: The result I want]

but I got lots of unresolved references so I think I'm doing something terribly wrong

I have two fragments the spinner is inside the second fragment
`custome_spinner.xml` is the custom layout file

Android Studio Version 3.1.2, `kotlin_version = '1.2.30'` and `gradle:3.1.2`

**CustomeSpinnerAdapter.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter

class customeSpinnerAdapter : BaseAdapter {
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return flag.length
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return null
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    val country: String
    val flag: String
    fun customeSpinnerAdapter(context: Context, name: String, image: String) {
        this.country = name
        this.flag = image

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    }

    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner)
        spinner_image.setImageResource(flag)
        spinner_country.setText(country)
        return view
    }
}
```

**custom_spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/us" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_country"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Custom Text"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The widget inside **fragment_second.xml**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/from_textView" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem lies in customeSpinnerAdapter.kt

```
  customeSpinnerAdapter.kt
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter

class customeSpinnerAdapter : BaseAdapter{
    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return flag.length
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return null
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    val country:String
    val flag:String
    //Add this
    val inflater : LayoutInflater

    fun customeSpinnerAdapter(context:Context,name:String,image:String){
        this.country = name
        this.flag = image

        //val inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        inflater  = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    }
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_spinner)
        spinner_image.setImageResource(flag)
        spinner_country.setText(country)
        return view
    }
}
```